# I am getting error when deploying on GIT but works on local machine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github

I have an angular project which have the following settings:

```
var app = angular.module('viewerApp', 
    ['ngFileSaver', 'tw.services.fileReader', 
     'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 
     'tw.directives.clickOutside', 'ngResource']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/some-page.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
});

app.controller('topicCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    ........
});
```

It works on local machine but when I deploy it on github (on gh-pages) I get the following error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module viewerApp due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module tw.directives.clickOutside due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'tw.directives.clickOutside' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=tw.directives.clickOutside
>   minErr/<@https://github.wdf.sap.corp/pages/UA-Prototypes-Group/test/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>   module/<@https://github.wdf.sap.corp/pages/UA-Prototypes-Group/test/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1986:17
>   ensure@https://github.wdf.sap.corp/pages/UA-Prototypes-Group/test/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1910:38 .......

Here is my html where I add the reference to the clickOutside:

```
<html
ng-app="viewerApp"
ng-controller="headerCtrl"
dir="ltr">
   <head>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-file-reader/angular-file-reader.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-click-outside/angular-click-outside.js"></script>

    <script src="public/lib/angular-file-saver/dist/angular-file-saver.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/viewer-app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/viewer-ctrl.js"></script>
```

I checked and the angular-click-outside.js file exists, it is in node_modules directory.

Could anybody explain what is this error and why do I get it only on git website and not on localhost?

Comment: it seems you missed to add: tw.directives.clickOutside file path

Comment: If you open Chrome dev tools, and go to sources, press Ctrl+P. Can you find the `angular-click-outside.js` file?

Comment: @Detilium No, I cannot find it, even if I can see it the github repository. Do you know what is the reason, and how to fix it?

Comment: @Detilium I fixed it. I simply downloaded the angular-click.js and added it manually to the project

Comment: Did you download it using the `npm` installer?